# Is the kernel loaded into memory for every user simultaneously using a Multi-User O.S. system?

Tags: operating-system

I have a doubt about loading kernel for every user using a Multi-User system. Every user's processes and programs are scheduled to CPU in a time-sharing fashion. But, do every user on the multi-user system have their individual kernel loaded in the main memory, or is there only one kernel loaded which is sort of distributed amongst the users?

Comment: For the major OSes, the kernel is loaded once at boot, and then through the magic of virtual addressing, every user process, no matter which user runs it has the same kernel address space (which is mapped to the one and only kernel). So no, each user does not have their own individual kernel. On the other hand, if you look up microkernels, you'll see that the user-level kernel services microkernels offer could be per-user or even per-process. But the major OSes aren't microkernels, they're monolithic kernels.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. But not everyone's terminal will be open all the time or open at the same time. Each one will also have their login window.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. That's user-level stuff. Same shared kernel.

Comment: If every user had their own kernel, how could the OS perform its primary purpose of managing resources?

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks. Wow, now it makes sense.